# Symfony2 routing with prefix bug

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, redirect

today all my symfony projects get broken for a very strange 'bug'.

My routing.yml file was:

```
luckyseven_admin_bundle:
    resource: "@LuckySevenAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /admin/
```

And my AdminBundle routing.yml file was:

```
admin_homepage:
    path:   /
    defaults:  { _controller: LuckySevenAdminBundle:Home:index }

...more...
```

Until today, all was working well. When I went to `mysite.com/admin` all works well. Since today, EVERY SYMFONY PROJECT that I had corrupted and the URL returns an error below (loop of redirects to the same page /admin).

> TOO MANY REDIRECT error .

Trying to debug with app_dev.php i found that in DEV environment it works well, while in PROD gives TOO MANY REDIRECTS, so i can't debug this problem.

I have this problem only with 'root pages with prefix'. In the example you can see a 'root' page (admin_homepage) that has a prefix /admin/. Pages like this will return the error.

Other pages (not root, like '/example') will work.

I can't understand why it works until today and why i have this problem only with 'root' paths (and only in PROD mode). Can you help me to understand?

**EDIT**

Using the same code that i posted before but moving the root path (admin_homepage) in the main routing.yml file changing the path '/' in '/admin', it works. So as i said, the problem is with 'root path' inside routing files that will be imported with a prefix.

Main routing.yml (working):

```
luckyseven_admin_bundle:
    resource: "@LuckySevenAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /admin/
admin_homepage:
    path:   /admin
    defaults:  { _controller: LuckySevenAdminBundle:Home:index }
```

AdminBundle routing.yml file (working):

```
admin_test:
    path: /test #it becames /admin/test
    defaults:  { _controller: LuckySevenAdminBundle:Home:index }
```

Security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls: 
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                always_use_default_target_path: false
                default_target_path: /admin
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/api, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: It can be a change in the code, a change in the dependencies or a change in configuration (I mean the project or server configuration or environment). You just have to find what changed since the last time it was working.

Comment: can we see `LuckySevenAdminBundle:Home:index`?

Comment: @1ed The problem is that nothing change, so i'm asking your help to understand what could be changed to interfer only with 'root' path. BTW I'm going to add a small EDIT to this question in few minutes

Comment: @Federico just one line of code, a normal $this->render. I've also tried with a brutal die(). On app_dev.php all is working file, on app.php too many redirects. I've edited the app.php in only one line to fix the 'trailing slash issue', but it always works.

Comment: @AlbertoFecchi Maybe not you changed something, but if it was working before and it is not now then something changed for sure. As it depends a lot of things and we have no access to your environment I can only say where to start to investigate. If the code not changed you should start to check the server configuration.

Comment: let's see your `security.yml`

Comment: @1ed of course you're right, i'm not asking for a precise answer, but i'm asking for a help to understand where to start my search. .htaccess files are the same, php code/routing files are the same. So, as you said, it could be something on server. Ok but... which rule allows 301 redirects only if i put 'root path' inside a routing.yml file that has a prefix? It makes no sense! the same url is working outside that file.

Comment: @Federico posted, but as said before it works for months.

Comment: Try changing app.php to $kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);  Might get a useful error message.  And check your production logs if you have not already.  At no point did you run composer update?  If not then it must be something on your server.  Is it your server or is it a shared host?  Lot's of things could have been adjusted.  I myself do not use a trailing slash on my prefixes so I suppose you could try prefix:   /admin but it probably won't help.  Does seem a bit strange to have both a prefix /admin as well as a path /admin.

Comment: Are You using SSL in Admin pages? Turn on chrome dev tools, set preserve log and inspect how Your redirects are occurring? I had similar problem, when someone decided to set `Strict-Transport-Security` header on my server, and I was doing some redirects from https to http, then browser would redirect any http request to https, my server from https to http, then browser from http to https.... Well You get an idea.